# Nested query missing expression

Tags: sql, oracle, nested, rownum

```
SELECT customer_id, company_code
FROM customer, commercial_cust
WHERE commercial_cust.FK_customer_id = customer.customer_id
(
SELECT payment_method, payment_date
FROM payment, cust_order
WHERE payment_link.FK_order_id = cust_order.order_id
(
SELECT order_id, payment_date, SUM(payment_ammount) payment_ammount
FROM cust_order, payment_link, payment
WHERE cust_order.FK_customer_id = customer.customer_id AND payment_link.FK_payment_id = payment.payment_id
)
GROUP BY payment_ammount.DESC
)
WHERE ROWNUM <=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cust_order)/4;
```

For a database assignment I have been asked to display a list of 25% more lucrative commercial customers. I have written this out but I keep getting a missing element error and I'm not sure where I am meant to put the semicolon (if it is the semicolon). I've tried moving it around and removing parts of the script but it doesn't seem to be working.

This will be hugely appreciated if somebody can help. The rest of the code is correct in terms of names etc.

Comment: missing expression i meant

Comment: There are many syntax error in your query. 1) The main query has two `where` clause. 2) After each where clause, a subquery is located, which is rubbish.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve and provide some sample data and expected data.

Comment: You have 3 different selects without any relationship (`UNION`, ...). I'm not sure about Oracle notation, bu I can't find any place where you can make `WHERE ... (...`. Explain relation between tables and intended result.

Comment: There are many many mistakes just from the first glance. 1) Your nesting is wrong, you cannot just write the nested selects into a where condition without any sense, you either put them in the from clause (probably what you desire since you want to work with the data) or you can condition them in the where clause. 2) Your group by should be on the columns which stay, not on the column you sum 3) The second select have a where condition on the nested table, that is also wrong you have to choose a different alias 4) learn to use joins instead of listing tables as they go - the proper way

Comment: You are learning SQL *now*, but use a join syntax that was made redundant in *1992*??? Aren't you being taught that a proper join contains the word `JOIN` as in `FROM customer c JOIN commercial_cust cc ON cc.FK_customer_id = c.customer_id`?

Comment: Yes.. we haven't been taught the JOIN method :o

Comment: Then quit that class and look for another.

Answer (score 1):

You should have shown what your tables contain, how they are related, and should have given sample data and expected result. So my answer may not match your requirement completely.

Let's simply look at how much a customer ordered: sum the order amount per customer, make sure the customer is a "commercial customer" and divide the results into 4 blocks keeping only the first (i.e. highest ranking) block.

```
select customer_id, sum_amount
from
(
  select 
    fk_customer_id as customer_id, 
    sum(order_amount) as sum_amount, 
    ntile(4) over (order by sum(order_amount) desc) as block
  from cust_order
  where fk_customer_id in (select fk_customer_id from commercial_cust)
  group by fk_customer_id
)
where block = 1
order by sum_amount desc;
```

If you want to use the payments instead, then do the same but join the payments to the orders and use that amount:

```
select customer_id, sum_amount
from
(
  select 
    o.fk_customer_id as customer_id, 
    sum(p.payment_ammount) as sum_amount, 
    ntile(4) over (order by sum(p.payment_ammount) desc) as block
  from cust_order co
  join payment_link pl on pl.fk_order_id = o.order_id
  join payment p on p.payment_id = pl.fk_payment_id
  where o.fk_customer_id in (select fk_customer_id from commercial_cust)
  group by o.fk_customer_id
)
where block = 1
order by sum_amount desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query instead, you ahve a lot of semantic and syntax errors:

```
SELECT customer_id, company_code, payment, cust_order, order_id, payment_date, SUM(payment_ammount) payment_ammount
FROM customer, commercial_cust, cust_order, payment_link, payment
WHERE commercial_cust.FK_customer_id = customer.customer_id
AND payment_link.FK_order_id = cust_order.order_id
AND cust_order.FK_customer_id = customer.customer_id AND payment_link.FK_payment_id = payment.payment_id
GROUP BY payment_ammount.DESC
HAVING ROWNUM <=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cust_order)/4;
```

Comment: Okay however the WHERE clause is outputting an error "partially recognised rules", and the reason why I used nested is because my assignment requires the use of nested queries

Comment: I made a typing error, please check my query again, I edited it.